# Is it possible to Login to Facebook using Parse with publish_actions and email permissions?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I'm searching for days trying to figure it out but I only find questions or old answers that seems not to be working anymore.

Loging in to Facebook with Parse is easy if you go through the tutorial, but if you want to do something "usefull" it just tells you to see the Facebook documentation. Which is not that clear, and for obvious reasons, doesn't make any reference to Parse.

So, the only way I could login without error was with this code:

```
   List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email");
   ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(myFrag, permissions, new LogInCallback() { ... });
```

or

```
   Collection<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
   ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithPublishPermissionsInBackground(myFrag, permissions, logInCallback);
```

But I need "publish_actions" permission as long as read "email"..

Somewhere I read that I CAN NOT login asking for that permission. But on Facebook documentation all it says is that I SHOULD NOT.

So, is it possible? If yes or no, please, how can I do it?!! I really can not find any relevant info about it using the latest Facebook and Parse libs.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No.

With Parse, it seems that it is not possible indeed.

Either you get Read or Publish permissions.

To have both, you need to use linkWithPublishPermissionsInBackground or equivament to Read.